# Western Digital hard drive not initializing after being in storage for 3 months

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, hard-drive-recovery

I took my desktop with me abroad, and thought it would be smart to leave out my drive with all my personal pictures on it in a safe at my house. After plugging it into my computer when I got back, my desktop failed to get past BIOS, and the few times it did windows would be stuck on the logo screen. At first I thought it was with my computer, but that was not the case, after unplugging my drive the computer continued to work as normally. The drive I hot swapped into the computer as the computer was running, I confirmed that this worked with another drive that mounted, and tried the 'failed' drive in 3 other SATA ports... Nothing.

Soon after I entered disk utility and found that the drive was not initializing. I unplugged it, and plugged it in via USB through an interface. Same issue - not initializing.

I tried partition find and mount, all three search settings - still same issue. Couldn't find any partition. I confirmed that it also didn't work in a Windows 7 computer as I updated my desktop while abroad (drive not in computer) and thought that may be the issue.

I decided to check the SMART status of the drive and it reports healthy!!

What happened?

This may sound stupid, but was it like an old car that sat in the garage too long without being started and now it won't start?

Specs: Western Digital WD10EACS
OS: Windows 10

Comment: Was the safe in a climate-controlled room while you were absent?

Comment: it wasnt in storage or anything - it was in my bedroom, never got to hot or too cold

Comment: What no backups of important data?

Comment: What update did you make to your system? If want to recover the data for this HDD do not initialize it.
You can try booting with a live Linux CD, it might be able to mount the partition.

Comment: Windows 8.1 -> Windows 10 @Techpumpkin_WD

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to access your data with Linux Live CD? Was the drive recognized there?

Comment: @Mighty_Miro_WD what do you suggest? ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu should work. As I understood there are no changes in the hardware and you only upgraded the OS. Was this HDD just a storage one or does it have an OS on it? And by Disk Utility do you mean Windows Disk Management?

Comment: HDD was in storage (just files on it). Ubuntu didn't work. I'm taking it to a specialist. We'll see!